# how to pass web browser window width to rails controller?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any simple way to pass the pixel width of the clients browser to the rails controller, so that the controller can set the layout used dynamically based on the layout that best matches the screen size?

Comment: That's normally handled with pure front-end techniques (ex. CSS Media Queries); the server-side shan't care about that

Comment: Hi @Mksys, Welcome to Stackoverflow, Yes, the best way is to handle into the FE itself using media queries, If in case you need to pass some value to FE, either you can sent it as URL Param's or through AJAX call. However, that should be avoided atleast for this case.

Comment: The problem is that I want to know what the layout should be, so that I can do different things in the controller - so say if a layout is three boxes wide, I load 3 x 10 (30) stories to display on the page, versus if the page is wider and should use a layout that is four boxes wide, I want the controller to load 4 x 10 (40) stories... So it would be nice to have the controller have the ability to make some of those calculations - and it seems to me it would work well to pass or have the sever able to detect this?

Comment: Basically media queries are useful, but don't let the controller figure out things that would help optimize what the page is doing

Comment: Then you'll need JS to interact with the server. First, the HTML page loads with a few "stories" in it, then the JS of the page will go fetch a certain number of additional "stories" depending on the "layout/width" of the device and add them to the content.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are multiple ways to pass the window size to the server if you really wanted to.

One way of doing this would be to append a parameter to all links/forms:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', (event) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((a) => {
    let url = new URL(a.href);
    url.searchParams.set('inner_width', window.innerWidth);
    a.href = url.toString();
  });
  document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach((form) => {
    let input = form.elements["inner_width"];
    if (!input) {
      input = document.createElement('input');
      input.name = 'inner_width';
      input.type = 'hidden';
      form.appendChild(input);
    }
    input.value = window.innerWidth;
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="/foo">Foo</a>
<a href="/bar">Bar</a>

<form>
  <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

Of course this is extremely inefficient since you are combing through the entire DOM and altering every link on the page. The `resize` event also fires repeatedly when resizing the window so you may [need throttling or debouncing](https://bencentra.com/code/2015/02/27/optimizing-window-resize.html).

In Rails you can access any query string parameters through the params hash:

```
columns = case params[:inner_width].to_i
when > 1200
  4
when 1200..2500
  6
else
  10
end
```

Another alternative is using a cookie:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', (event) => {
  document.cookie = `innerWidth=${window.innerWidth}`;
});
```

You can access cookies in Rails through the `cookies` hash:

```
columns = case cookies[:inner_width].to_i
when > 1200
  4
when 1200..2500
  6
else
  10
end
```

Or you could even make a crazy catch-all event handler for clicks and form submissions or any other event that causes a reload.

But really a better idea is using AJAX to lazy load more posts to fill the available space. This avoids making your server responsibly for what is really a frontend problem - and will actually be capable of handling resizes. The are tons of tutorials and libraries for what is basically an endless scroll - combined with pagination on the server side.